# Forward fill non na values with last observation carried forwards in Python

Tags: python, pandas

Suppose I had a column in a dataframe like :

| colname |
| --- |
| Na |
| Na |
| Na |
| 1 |
| 2 |
| 3 |
| 4 |
| Na |
| Na |
| Na |
| Na |
| 2 |
| 8 |
| 5 |
| 44 |
| Na |
| Na |

Does anyone know of a function to forward fill the Non NA values with the first value in the non na run? To produce :

| colname |
| --- |
| Na |
| Na |
| Na |
| 1 |
| 1 |
| 1 |
| 1 |
| Na |
| Na |
| Na |
| Na |
| 2 |
| 2 |
| 2 |
| 2 |
| Na |
| Na |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`GroupBy.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html) with [`GroupBy.first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.first.html) by compare values for missing values by [`Series.isna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isna.html) with cumulative sum by [`Series.cumsum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.cumsum.html), last correct `NaN`s by [`Series.where`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.where.html) with [`Series.duplicated`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.duplicated.html):

```
s = df['colNaNme'].isna().cumsum()
df['colNaNme'] = df.groupby(s)['colNaNme'].transform('first').where(s.duplicated())
print (df)
    colNaNme
0        NaN
1        NaN
2        NaN
3        1.0
4        1.0
5        1.0
6        1.0
7        NaN
8        NaN
9        NaN
10       NaN
11       2.0
12       2.0
13       2.0
14       2.0
15       NaN
16       NaN
```

Or filter only non missing values by invert mask `m` and processing only these groups:

```
m = df['colNaNme'].isna()
df.loc[~m, 'colNaNme'] = df[~m].groupby(m.cumsum())['colNaNme'].transform('first')
print (df)
    colNaNme
0        NaN
1        NaN
2        NaN
3        1.0
4        1.0
5        1.0
6        1.0
7        NaN
8        NaN
9        NaN
10       NaN
11       2.0
12       2.0
13       2.0
14       2.0
15       NaN
16       NaN
```

Solution with non `groupby`:

```
m = df['colNaNme'].isna()
m1 = m.cumsum().shift().bfill()
m2 = ~m1.duplicated() & m.duplicated(keep=False)    

df['colNaNme'] = df['colNaNme'].where(m2).ffill().mask(m)
print (df)
    colNaNme
0        NaN
1        NaN
2        NaN
3        1.0
4        1.0
5        1.0
6        1.0
7        NaN
8        NaN
9        NaN
10       NaN
11       2.0
12       2.0
13       2.0
14       2.0
15       NaN
16       NaN
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try `groupby` and `cumsum` with `shift` and `transform('first')`:

```
>>> df.groupby(df['colname'].isna().ne(df['colname'].isna().shift()).cumsum()).transform('first')
   colname
0      NaN
1      NaN
2      NaN
3        1
4        1
5        1
6        1
7      NaN
8      NaN
9      NaN
10     NaN
11       2
12       2
13       2
14       2
15     NaN
16     NaN
>>>
```

Or try something like:

```
>>> x = df.groupby(df['colname'].isna().cumsum()).transform('first')
>>> x.loc[~x.duplicated()] = np.nan
>>> x
   colname
0      NaN
1      NaN
2      NaN
3        1
4        1
5        1
6        1
7      NaN
8      NaN
9      NaN
10     NaN
11       2
12       2
13       2
14       2
15     NaN
16     NaN
>>>
```

Comment: Second solution failed if use `for index=11` is `colNaNme=1`